# Application Launcher for Hyper-V Server

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

We are currently in the process of setting up a HyperV R2 Server machine. Though there's not a lot we need to do wihtin the HyperV Server itself, the command line is sure minimalistic.

There are a few administrative / Hardware Monitoring tools that we want to run on he machine itself (accessed through remote desktop).

I am looking for a simple program/application launcher where we can hook up these maintenance tools (and one to open a new cmd.exe window in case I habitually close the one I'm working in!)

However, all tools I tried by now more or less assume explorer is present, and fail in different ways. Before I go and write a simple one myself, any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Finally [wrote my own](http://www.cherea.de/apps/mulaunch/mulaunch.html) :)

Simple, but does the job.